# When does Kafka topic-level configuration changes take effect?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

There are documents such as the ones below stating that Kafka topic-level configuration changes can be taken place while Kafka cluster is still running.

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/dynamic-config.html#changing-topic-configurations-dynamically

The questions I have are:

- When will the configuration change take effect? Is restart of Kafka cluster required?
  https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Kafka-alter-topic-requires-broker-restart-to-take-effect/td-p/44396
- Are there differences for config change effect to kick in different topic-level config? http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs